# Unable to write the contents of a text file selected from the table

Tags: c#, mysql

I take a sample from the table to get the test file, which is written to the table under the BLOB data type, and write this file to the PC, but instead of the original contents of the file, it writes its name from the table.

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection conn;
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand cmd;
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader myData;

conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection();
cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand();

string SQL;
UInt32 FileSize;
byte[] rawData;
FileStream fs;

conn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;uid=root;" +
    "pwd=1111;database=test";

SQL = "SELECT fileName, fileSize, fileBlob FROM file WHERE id=5";

try
{
    conn.Open();

    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.CommandText = SQL;

    myData = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if (!myData.HasRows)
        throw new Exception("There are no BLOBs to save");

    myData.Read();

    FileSize = myData.GetUInt32(myData.GetOrdinal("fileSize"));
    rawData = new byte[FileSize];

    myData.GetBytes(myData.GetOrdinal("fileBlob"), 0, rawData, 0, (int)FileSize);

    fs = new FileStream(@"C:\newfile.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
    fs.Write(rawData, 0, (int)FileSize);
    fs.Close();

    MessageBox.Show("File successfully written to disk!",
        "Success!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);

    myData.Close();
    conn.Close();
}
catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex.Number + " has occurred: " + ex.Message,
        "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

Comment: I really seems like the file name is written to the blob column instead of the file contents. If you run this query in workbench (or whatever), what is the length of `fileBlob`?

Comment: The size of the original file that is loaded into the table is 713 bytes

Comment: That's not what I'm asking. What is the size of the data in the database, in the [fileBlob] column? Is it the same size as the the file name converted to bytes? Your code should work, I think your problem is up stream.

Comment: fileSize = 713 bytes,this is the file size